# facebook js sdk: How to get bigger picture of like?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I am using facebook jssdk

```
FB.api("me/friends?",{
        fields:'id,name,picture,likes,likes.picture,likes.name,likes.category',
}
```

I wish to get bigger picture of like

```
FB.api("me/friends?",{
            fields:'id,name,picture,likes,likes.picture.type(large),likes.name,likes.category',
    }
```

type(large) does not work. It work while getting only likes me/likes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 FB.api("me/friends?",{
      fields:'id,name,picture,likes.fields(picture.type(large)),likes.name,likes.category', 
        }
```